# When I press the o key on macbook pro i get multiple o's

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

When I press the o key on macbook pro i get multiple o's . They also pop up in the middle of writing other words as well.How can i fix this. The o's run across the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the key contact is contaminated.

Simple starter options would be...

- Switch off the machine.
- Repeatedly tap the key, 20 or more times, firmly but not too forcibly.
- Turn the machine vertically & repeat.
- Use a can of compressed air to blow out any dust/bits from under the keys.

If still no joy, I'd recommend professional repair.

Comment: Thanks. I tried tapping the keys regularly and vertically with machine switched off. Going to buy condensed air today to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but just for your info.. Found an app that solves this issue:

https://github.com/Aahung/Unshaky
Hope this helps